# If I leave during the pick phase will I be penalized?

Tags: dota-2

Today I just opened my console and used the disconnect command then left the game because my Team had picked 4 carries and it would surely be a loss.

If I do this frequently, will I be penalized?

Comment: Dont do it and you won't get penalized. You can be reported and  yes several early abandons leads up to low priority pool. That having been said this kind of behaviour is wrong and makes you look like a bad teamplayer and a bad player in general. Would you leave a game becuase you have no carry ? Because if you did then you don't know a thing about DotA and playing more games with severals carries could teach you a lot. You can't judge a game by its pick **never** You can never know how well the enemy team will perform. What if they giveup some early kills, then your lategame become monstruous

Comment: After several pub matches what I've learned is: If your teammates don't even know how to pick, they don't know how to play.

Comment: @WizLiz this platform is not to question someones action and tell him to stop "bad" behavior. Furthermore to all other people: i do not know why you would downvote the question since it is legit

Comment: @Wandang if leaving is punished by Valve in several ways, does this question concern illegal content ?

Comment: @WizLiz Wait, illegal content? I don't think leaving a game of Dota 2 constitutes an illegal action.

Comment: @Wandang: It's might not be that useful. Leaving games forces nine other people to go through the matchmaking system again,  wait for everything to load, and then pick again. If someone doesn't think people should be doing that in the first place, then it makes sense that they wouldn't think it really matters what the repercussions are.

Comment: @Yuki not necessarily Illegal but since its punished I personnaly find the question borderline. Still i didn't vote to close it or anything, just giving my opinion on which point Wandang was right, I shouldnt have. But being an experienced DotA player, this a bugged me a little.

Comment: I've won with some hilarious 5 carry lineups recently, i personally played a support slardar with my friend on a support alchemist.  Our other 3 carries were crying about the picks, but the -armor synergy was perfect. You can play a hero outside of it's natural role, normally without too much of a problem.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, leaving during the picking phase has given abandons since around August 30th, 2013, and will put you into Low Priority queue if continued. The only time you can leave without getting an abandon is during the loading phase or after someone else does.

Besides just getting an abandons though, it is also pretty rude. Sometimes people will get really upset and falsely report you for it even.

Comment: On the topic of it being rude: I know a fair amount of people who report this kind of quitter (regardless of team), as they've just ruined the game for 9 other people and wasted everyone's time.  So that could be considered a "penalty".

Comment: @John Yeah, people reporting you erroneously is an additional risk I guess. I should probably add that.